# Как размыть div не трогая текст внутри которого он есть

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть div, внутри которого есть текст. Мне нужно размыть задний фон не размывая текст внутри него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да много вариантов, к примеру завернуть в родитель два блока, тот который сзади размыть `filter: blur(10px);`.

Но судя по приложенному макету, вам может подойти вариант ещё проще, вместо filter, использовать backdrop-filter, к примеру, `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)

Comment: @Sviatoslav вы хоть бы ответ засчитали